# Maven projects versions stored in a database managed by a version server and a web interface?

Tags: database, maven, release, versions

I am thinking to have a Database that store all projects and their versions: both "under development" (let's say on TRUNK) and "RELEASED" (on some release branch).
So, keeping them so, we can link them and their versions and keep control of all these through an centralized GUI. Like everytime when we change a project version from GUI, all projects versions are changing according with their POMs versions as are stored inside of the Database.

An example would be this:
Projects A, B, C, D, E, F

- Project A version 1.0.0 depends of Project B version 2.3.0 and Project C version 1.2.5
- Project C version 1.2.5 depends of Project D Version 3.1.0
- Project D version 3.1.0 dependes of Project E 1.2.1 and
  Project F 3.2.4

> ```
> A 1.0.0
>        \_ B 2.3.0
>        |_ C 1.2.5
>                  \_ D 3.1.0
>                            \_E 1.2.1
>                            |_F 3.2.4
> ```

and

- Project A version 1.1.0 depends of Project B version 2.4.0 Project C version 1.3.5
- Project C version 1.3.5 depends of Project D Version 3.2.0
- Project D version 3.2.0 dependes of Project E 1.3.1 and Project F 3.3.4

> ```
>   A 1.1.0
>          \_ B 2.4.0
>          |_ C 1.3.5
>                    \_ D 3.2.0
>                              \_E 1.3.1
>                              |_F 3.3.4
> ```

So, when we change the Project A version from the UI, all the dependencies versions are changing accordingly, based on the Database stored versions and links between projects.
So that you have "the big picture" every time when you're curious to see how your project version si looking from the dependecies perspective and what projects versions have been changed from a release to another.

On the other hand, this maybe could be extended like when we want to perform a project release, we should just change versions through UI and these changes are passed to the projects POMs.

Is this a feasible idea from your perspective, guys?
Thanks

Comment: Nevermind, we were able to create a system capable to perform all described above and a bit more, and it's working like a charm. From now on, goodbye manual release procedure, update dependencies versions etc. But thanks for your all of your "answers and contribution" :)